# how to convert kml polygons geometry data to google polygon coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing, kml

I have a KML file which has multiple polygons in it. But i want to use those polygons on google maps. but there is know way to get those polygons on google maps except adding kml layer to maps. i have a kml structure like this

```
            <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>
            74.217933,21.927974,0.0 74.192401,21.925983,0.0 74.178174,21.9321,0.0 74.164435,
            21.946759,0.0 74.146569,21.952709,0.0 74.143914,21.947538,0.0 74.132601,21.950536,
            0.0 74.051588,21.926869,0.0 74.017921,21.906915,0.0 73.940306,21.870938,0.0 73.915448,
            21.858942,0.0 73.886445,21.854553,0.0 73.872501,21.841586,0.0 73.838791,21.84398,0.0 73.806905,
            21.836495,0.0 73.795757,21.824716,0.0 73.803676,21.820348,0.0 73.80714,21.809796,0.0 73.820618,
            21.809518,0.0 73.827683,21.809372,0.0 73.832522,21.800558,0.0 73.826672,21.798208,0.0 73.827101,
            21.792052,0.0 73.837845,21.789244,0.0 73.829416,21.783746,0.0 73.834614,21.773961,0.0 73.824811,
            21.765365,0.0 73.825474,21.758233,0.0 73.833825,21.754807,0.0 73.836309,21.746688,0.0 73.854042,
            21.734175,0.0 73.867046,21.718145,0.0 73.880933,21.715067,0.0 73.890513,21.697823,0.0 73.894875,
            21.676056,0.0 73.887974,21.65309,0.0 73.860169,21.642183,0.0 73.851173,21.646202,0.0 73.849492,
            21.638522,0.0 73.8385,21.632985,0.0 73.830138,21.64257,0.0 73.824512,21.639684,0.0 73.814003,
            21.644056,0.0 73.812068,21.63986,0.0 73.780725,21.628594,0.0 73.781443,21.618331,0.0 73.799974,
            21.603551,0.0 73.814216,21.600913,0.0 73.834905,21.520264,0.0 73.853244,21.497465,0.0 73.863805,
            21.497775,0.0 73.872545,21.505354,0.0 73.866347,21.506724,0.0 73.864119,21.512335,0.0 73.876908,
            21.512107,0.0 73.878389,21.504621,0.0 73.905265,21.515516,0.0 73.904175,21.524316,0.0 73.917731,
            21.51927,0.0 73.921527,21.525118,0.0 73.927295,21.52499,0.0 73.932321,21.51203,0.0 73.945839,
            21.516515,0.0 73.951749,21.512152,0.0 73.954664,21.54076,0.0 73.9603,21.541543,0.0 73.966245,
            21.521829,0.0 73.982393,21.522285,0.0 73.974727,21.534395,0.0 73.974835,21.543543,0.0 73.98301,
            21.540612,0.0 73.993197,21.543254,0.0 73.997254,21.538695,0.0 74.002372,21.541435,0.0 74.000442,
            21.545559,0.0 74.005804,21.552619,0.0 74.030314,21.545087,0.0 74.037638,21.550482,0.0 74.036571,
            21.545508,0.0 74.04362,21.54239,0.0 74.044572,21.548019,0.0 74.047052,21.544556,0.0 74.053833,
            21.547389,0.0 74.053711,21.5553,0.0 74.053787,21.555772,0.0 74.053811,21.555918,0.0 74.054203,
            21.55773,0.0 74.054949,21.557767,0.0 74.059521,21.565624,0.0 74.072109,21.568334,0.0 74.060284,
            21.57961,0.0 74.053196,21.596951,0.0 74.039321,21.599039,0.0 74.035168,21.622388,0.0 74.052703,
            21.633526,0.0 74.058269,21.62828,0.0 74.068697,21.631812,0.0 74.067451,21.645073,0.0 74.058233,
            21.655136,0.0 74.064248,21.669534,0.0 74.087031,21.671719,0.0 74.093986,21.661162,0.0 74.10084,
            21.659678,0.0 74.099919,21.644633,0.0 74.083675,21.629971,0.0 74.09551,21.604941,0.0 74.099564,
            21.604905,0.0 74.094999,21.621662,0.0 74.105406,21.620227,0.0 74.107536,21.610181,0.0 74.12545,
            21.628568,0.0 74.111203,21.665116,0.0 74.118144,21.676485,0.0 74.146465,21.665937,0.0 74.156023,
            21.673993,0.0 74.200822,21.680146,0.0 74.217933,21.685328,0.0 74.231912,21.689561,0.0 74.266462,
            21.706124,0.0 74.26489,21.697462,0.0 74.272554,21.68755,0.0 74.298756,21.686718,0.0 74.312301,
            21.699125,0.0 74.326192,21.691602,0.0 74.367473,21.692807,0.0 74.385528,21.726404,0.0 74.467352,
            21.732436,0.0 74.468378,21.749132,0.0 74.459832,21.774116,0.0 74.462667,21.78612,0.0 74.484092,
            21.792158,0.0 74.491315,21.779393,0.0 74.501576,21.782545,0.0 74.500208,21.806491,0.0 74.506975,
            21.817289,0.0 74.513637,21.858936,0.0 74.513663,21.877396,0.0 74.51368,21.889811,0.0 74.522749,
            21.89911,0.0 74.524199,21.911394,0.0 74.50982,21.919968,0.0 74.512741,21.932346,0.0 74.509109,
            21.936911,0.0 74.486995,21.943298,0.0 74.490625,21.950687,0.0 74.480305,21.958732,0.0 74.469639,
            21.96187,0.0 74.457396,21.959208,0.0 74.446213,21.967608,0.0 74.434266,21.999017,0.0 74.452246,
            22.004736,0.0 74.443634,22.011152,0.0 74.438996,22.021142,0.0 74.443756,22.022793,0.0 74.438797,
            22.025297,0.0 74.431772,22.03024,0.0 74.387504,22.020222,0.0 74.375784,22.000424,0.0 74.3445,
            21.974979,0.0 74.307772,21.971813,0.0 74.296481,21.962447,0.0 74.290943,21.942557,0.0 74.281505,
            21.932913,0.0 74.217933,21.927974,0.0
            </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
```

I want this to be look like this to use in the maps api

```
             var polypoints = [         
              {lat:19.135375992895, lng:73.4651621426548}, 
              {lat:19.136223, lng:73.466679}, 
              {lat:19.134651, lng:73.475435}, 
              {lat:19.123618, lng:73.485494}, 
              {lat:19.129928, lng:73.490183}, 
              {lat:19.129584, lng:73.525777}, 
              {lat:19.127386, lng:73.534734}, 
              {lat:19.118468, lng:73.54187}, 
              {lat:19.140901, lng:73.545559}, 
              {lat:19.148871, lng:73.53763}, 
              {lat:19.146312, lng:73.533552}, 
              {lat:19.156782, lng:73.530371}, 
              {lat:19.159095, lng:73.54211}, 
              {lat:19.17804, lng:73.53518}, 
              {lat:19.175427, lng:73.544162},
              {lat:19.185196, lng:73.544325}, 
              {lat:19.183185, lng:73.565055}, 
              {lat:19.188709, lng:73.565395}, 
              {lat:19.192421, lng:73.575895}, 
              {lat:19.188721, lng:73.583836}, 
              {lat:19.19424, lng:73.596896}, 
              {lat:19.193097, lng:73.608924}, 
              {lat:19.1994380820247, lng:73.6099695718475}, 
              {lat:19.21112, lng:73.611896}, 
              {lat:19.216131, lng:73.622976}, 
              {lat:19.205074, lng:73.631254}, 
              {lat:19.218492, lng:73.643544}, 
              {lat:19.240521, lng:73.662225}, 
              {lat:19.238587, lng:73.672536}, 
              {lat:19.242568, lng:73.685665}, 
              {lat:19.251789, lng:73.69392}, 
              {lat:19.26913, lng:73.690388}, 
              {lat:19.291075, lng:73.668081}, 
              {lat:19.302024, lng:73.672406}, 
              {lat:19.304008, lng:73.681705}, 
              {lat:19.310702, lng:73.684406}, 
              {lat:19.324347, lng:73.706757}, 
              {lat:19.335062, lng:73.742001},
              {lat:19.335283, lng:73.748165}, 
              {lat:19.323247, lng:73.742947}, 
              {lat:19.330931, lng:73.773929}, 
              {lat:19.341891, lng:73.773059}, 
              {lat:19.336424, lng:73.77772}, 
              {lat:19.337174, lng:73.789155}, 
              {lat:19.33064, lng:73.795471}
                    ];
                    var poly11 = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: polypoints});
```

i have 350 kml polygons geometries

how to parse these records or convert those files

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? I'm actually curious about this too and just came across it.

Comment: Yeah, same here. I upvoted the question.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)) that render the KML using native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects.  Note that these third party parsers are subject to the same domain restriction for XmlHttpRequest, so the KML must be on the same domain as the web page or served through a proxy.

[example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160514_PointInPolygon.kml) (and your KML from the related question: [How to identify placemark id of kml layer from given latitude and longitude is present inside that placemark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225563/how-to-identify-placemark-id-of-kml-layer-from-given-latitude-and-longitude-is-p))

Answer (score 0):

You only have to open your .kml file with any code editor, for example Visual Studio code, then just select every `-7` and add before it `{ lng:`, then select every `21.` and add before it `, lat:` and at the end just add `},`. For this task it will be great to use shortcuts like `command D`, to select every matched value, just play with code editor tools and you will find the way to get what you want.

Comment: This was very old question. at that time I used regular expression from notepad++ and took all polygons.